# How to specify sonar.sourceEncoding property at folder level?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to specify different encoding for different folders in a project but within a single sonar properties file. How to specify the same ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Note that recent SonarQube versions are doing encoding auto-detection, and are also detecting BOM. If you have a concrete use case that is not supported, I encourage you to expose it on the SonarQube Google group.